# Winform Timer isn't running if statement when criteria is met

Tags: winforms

Hi I've come across either a weird bug or I'm not understanding something.
To cut a long story short I've had everything I'm wanting to work on my form working fine, I then decided to turn the form into an options menu so it was no longer the first form that appears when the application is launched and is shown after I click a button on a different form with the code

```
  private void ShowOptionsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formHomePage.Show();

    }
```

And for some reason a timer if statement is no longer working:

```
private void StartSubCheckT_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (subliminalMessages.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("list greater than 0 if");

            StartSubB.Enabled = true;

        }
```

there are other if statements below but are irrelevant and the point of this is to make a button usable once a list is greater than 0. I've created another test button to display the value and it shows that the sublminalMessages list is greater than 0

```
 private void testbutton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(subliminalMessages.Count.ToString());
    }
```

Which outputs at 1 which it should be from some other code that adds a value in at the beginning. But for some reason even with the subliminalmessages.count being greater than 0 the if statement is no longer being called ever since I'm making the form appear being called from another form from the button code above.

The subliminalMessages list is being populated and created on the same form

```
        public List<string> subliminalMessages = new List<string>();


   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default["Subliminal1"].ToString()))
        {
            subliminalMessages.Add(Settings.Default["Subliminal1"].ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("If worked");
        }

    }
```

There is a value in the Setting.Default that is being added

The button and timer are on the same form and the timer in question is enabled.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: It's difficult to help with so little to go on. Where is subliminalMessages getting populated? Is it on the same form? or on the other form (the one you turned into a menu). It'd be easier to help if you post more code or a stripped down version that shows the if statement not working. Is the subliminalmessages list on the same form as the timer? is the testbutton on the same form as the timer? Is it possible the timer is firing before the list is populated? Is the timer even enabled?

Comment: @HandbagCrab thanks for the reply just added the information you've asked

Comment: If I've got this correct, you have a form with your subliminalmessages on it and a timer. On form load you populate the submes list with the item from settings. At some point after that you're expecting the StartSubCheckT tick to fire and see that submes is > 0 and enable the button. What is the tick interval? is it possible it's not fired yet? I'd put a WriteLine as the first line in the tick and either just print out "tick" or write the Count of submes. That way you get an idea of when the timer is firing.

Comment: @HandbagCrab the intervals is set to 500. Already tried with a messagebox and the timer is firing but the if statement isn't working which is the reason why I'm so confused

Comment: 500 is less than a second so should be firing quite often. See my answer. It's not using the timer anymore but should do what you want if I've understood correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll have a stab at giving you an answer. But it's a little swerve from what you're doing now.

From what I understand of your code you are using the timer to enable/disable the StartSubB button. Or maybe just enable it.

Instead of relying on the timer which appears to not work why not use a `BindingList<string>`. This has an event called `ListChanged` which you can handle and then enable/disable your button.

Here's a test form I created:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<string> items;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        button3.Enabled = false;

        items = new BindingList<string>();
        items.ListChanged += Items_ListChanged;
    }

    private void Items_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        button3.Enabled = items.Count > 0;
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        items.Add("a");
    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (items.Count > 0)
            items.RemoveAt(items.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

I have a `BindingList<string>` called `items`. This is analagous with your `subliminalmessages` list but it's a `BindingList`. This type of list has a `ListChanged` event that fires when items are added or removed from the list. In the constructor we new up the `items` list and subscribe to the `ListChanged` event.

When the `Items_ListChanged` event fires `button3` is enabled or disabled based on whether `items.Count > 0` or not.

In `btnAdd_Click` we just add an item to the list.
In `btnRemove_Click` we check that there are some items then remove the last one.

If you were to run this you'd see that when we click the Add button, `button3` gets enabled. If we click the Remove button we'll see `button3` get disabled.

The only limitation of `BindingList` is that you can't add a range by passing in another List.

If you implement this and your button still doesn't activate then you'll probably need to post some more code. Strip out all the irrelevant stuff and put it in a new project that demonstrates the failure of the condition and either copy the code here or provide a link to download the project. The only reason the if statement should fail is if the list is actually empty.

Comment: Thanks Id give it a vote up if it would let me. I wasn't even aware of the concept of binding. I didn't mention it as I didn't even realise to test it but was having the same issue with another if statement but using the binding lists has fixed it. I am still curious to why the if statements were not working as the conditions were met but at least now the binding lists work and is actually a better alternative then my original design so again thanks.